# Rails relative_url doesnt adjust links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relative-url

After failed attempts with Passenger (see my other question), I managed to get rails running via a reverse proxy in a subfolder.
I added the lines

```
config.relative_url_root = "/App"
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/App"
```

to my environment. Now I can access my rails project under www.mySite.com/App. The problem is that the links /paths dont add the prefix "/App". So a link to "users" looks like
`www.mySite.com/users` instead of `www.mySite.com/App/users`.
How can I change this?

At least according to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root I did everything correct.

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` in your terminal and post the output here?

Comment: Here it is
http://pastebin.com/XWEjRZsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by adjusting my reverse proxy and my rails config as follows.
This is my corresponding apache file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /path/to/App/public
ProxyPass /App http://127.0.0.1:9292/App
ProxyPassReverse /App http://127.0.0.1:9292/App
</VirtualHost>
```

My config.ru looks like this:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
map '/App' do
  run Rails.application
end
```

The mentioned environments variables are set in /config/environment.rb. I am not sure if they are still needed:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/App"
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/App"
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']  = "/App"
ENV['ROOT_URL']  = "/App"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you ever figure out the optimal configuration? I have exactly the same problem where the asset URLs are fine but the links are not prefixed by the sub-app. I am using nginx with Puma.

Comment: I tried several configurations based on the given solutions. I found two minimal solutions: either just config.relative_url_root = "/App", or config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/App". The file config.ru has to be modified...
. Using environment variables, I could just get to pages, but assets (images, js, and css) where not handled...

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4.2, I had the same need and resolved modifying some configuration files. Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :mytm do
     ....
  end 
end
```

This do not require any modification to the application.

Furthermore, you have to reconfigure the asset pipeline, in /config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "/app/asset"
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but I think what you're describing is essentially namespacing all of your controllers under `"/App"` or something like that. This would be in your `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace "App" do

  # Put your resources here, as however you defined them before, e.g.:  
  resources :users, :decks, :cards, :revs, :sessions

end
```

Comment: I tried this before; doing this results in `App/users is not a supported controller`